# IMemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync returns null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, memorycache

I have a lot of `NullReferenceException` exceptions on the line `if (foosDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out var foo))` and I cannot in any way reproduce the issue.

Stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MyProject.Service.Baz(Guid id) in CustomClass.cs:line 900
   at MyProject.Service.BazFeature(Guid id) in CustomClassCaller.cs:line 288
```

line 900 is the line in question. It is a direct reference to the dictionary: `if (foosDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out var foo))`.

Below is the code that leads to the problem line:

```cs
public Foo Baz(Guid id) 
{

Func<Task<Dictionary<Guid, Foo>>> createDictionary =
    async () => (await repository.GetFoos()).ToDictionary(sm => sm.Id);

var foosDictionary = await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync<Dictionary<Guid, Foo>>(
    "cacheKey",
    async cacheEntry =>
    {
        cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        return await createDictionary();
    });

if (foosDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out var foo))
{
    return foo;
}

}
// also there's the remaining code, but it shouldn't execute and it is lower than line 900. Anyway, here it is.

var newDictionary = await createDictionary();

if (newDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out var newFoo))
{
    fooDictionary = newDictionary;

    return newFoo;
}

throw new Exception("Error");
```

The Usual Suspects are:

- `await repository.GetFoos()` - it uses `Dapper.QueryAsync` method to get `IEnumerable<Foo>` and it can't return null. Anyway, I tried hardcoding null return - and goes the next step
- `.ToDictionary()` - it will throw on `null`. And it does if I hardcode the null return. Also it has different stacktrace and points to `GetOrCreateAsync`, not the line of code in question.
- `GetOrCreateAsync` - all the other suspects will throw and give different stack trace so this must be it. This method returns `null`, but I can't figure out how and why.

Like, if there is `null` on the cache key, it should go and create the value. `createDictionary` can't return null so it's out of the question. So...how does that even happen? Why?

Memory cache is registered in Startup like this: `services.AddMemoryCache()`. I don't know whether it's Scoped or Singleton and the Microsoft docs don't address it in a straightforward way.

The app is ASP.NET Core 3.1, `GetOrCreateAsync` extension method is from v6.0.0, but the actual implementation (or so it seems) gets passed as v3.1.0.

How can I resolve the issue? Can `GetOrCreateAsync` really return null in some cases? If so, how to reproduce them?

PS. I've thought about thread 1 getting the entry and then thread 2 somehow nullifying it, but that shouldn't work since thread 1 already has the reference to the dictionary. Right?

Comment: Full stack trace, please. It seems possible that you're experiencing a threading issue accessing the dictionary itself.

Comment: I can't share the whole stack trace. I'll try to add as much as I can.

Comment: Sounds like an treading issue.

Comment: @GuruStron yeah, probably. I just can't figure out how to reproduce it? On which step do I need to freeze Thread 1 and execute the same operation on Thread 2?

I tried freezing it after getting the cache entry, during its setup - nothing. No `null`s. :\

So if you can come up with some possible repro scenarios, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Or maybe...this is a threading issue not in my code, but in the code of IMemoryCache? In that case, I can't possible freeze the thread in their inner operations. 

If that's the case, looks like I have to abstract the cache away in a locking wrapper.

Comment: `Dictionary` is not thread-safe, so if you're adding new values to it elsewhere at the same time as reading from it, you could have problems.

Comment: Is line 900 this?: `if (foosDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out var foo))`

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yeah, it is not thread-safe. But how does that relate to the question?

The problem is that **IMemoryCache returns null*. No one is manipulating the keyed cache dictionary. Multiple threads do not do anything with the dictionary - they only might differently populate the cache entry. And that shouldn't be a problem, since each thread has its own reference to the dictionary if it ever gets rewritten. If I read the whole situation right, that is.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yes, it is. It is the line 900 and the only way it to be `nullReference` is if the `foosDictionary` variable is `null`.

Comment: > Dictionary is not thread-safe, so if you're adding new values to it elsewhere at the same time as reading from it, you could have problems. 
Oh, you've expanded the answer. Yeah, I see where you're going with that, but that's not the case. The dictionary only might get replaced by another one, but no dictionary is being modified in any way. Hope that clarifies the situation.

Comment: That does clarify things. That is very strange then.

Comment: Yeah, the only manipulated by multiple threads thing is the IMemoryCache itself. That's why I can't get it - even if it's not thread-safe and Thread 1 might get the Dictionary populated by Thread 2, it still should get the Dictionary? 

If Thread 1 has the reference to the dictionary, no one can nullify it, can it?

Comment: I've also encountered a problem in the past that logs point not to the actual line with error but at least we've got the method. In that case, the problem might be lower or upper. Upper lines are discussed, lower lines are trivial. WTF indeed...

Comment: It seems that the GetOrCreateAsync method can end up calling the factory method multiple times, which one eventually winning (I guess). I can't really understand how it would ever return a `null` result. Unless `repository.GetFoos()` can return `null` and really the error is just bubbling up weirdly from there, I don't quite see what's happening.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar my thoughts exactly. But I even hardcoded `GetFoos()`  to return `null`, and the exception points out to `CreateOrGetAsync`, not the line 900.
If repo returns null, the stack trace is:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheExtensions.GetOrCreateAsync[TItem](IMemoryCache cache, Object key, Func`2 factory)
   at MyProject.Service.Baz(Guid id) in CustomClass.cs:line 892
   at MyProject.Service.BazFeature(Guid id) in CustomClassCaller.cs:line 288

Comment: You are using the standard memory cache and not a custom implementation, right?

Comment: For diagnostics purposes, you could incorporate [this code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8f7761af3763d0b84acefbb117ed6becd83061d1/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs) into your application and add some additional logging. In case you're wondering, `.GetOrCreateAsync` is an extension method ([code here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5f0cb44cf4ee637dfbb2468fcc260b49bc680e9d/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L105)).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yes, I use the standard memory cache. `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache` is the interface, and whatever ASP.NET Core 3.1 supplies as an implementation in `services.AddMemoryCache()`.

Yes, I forgot that Caching is open source and I could use the code itself! Great idea! Though, I use v3.1 implementation and this seems to be the latest implementation :\
Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Ah, yes. I believe you can find the older version [here](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/releases/tag/v3.1.26). Once extracted, it seems to be under `extensions-3.1.26/src/Caching/Memory/src`.